# Google Sheets VLOOKUP returning Syntax Analysis Error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

[image]

Please take a look at the image.
I am just testing to lookup for UID "20" and return it's value (which is 20..) but no matter my tests it is always returning Syntax analysis ERROR.

You can see with the orange marking that the range is selected correctly, the "20" is present in the UID but yet "ERROR" displayed. I'm picking up the 1st column from the VLOOKUP.

Why is that?

Thanks

Comment: Any number within **quotes** or **speech marks** are treated as **text**. try without using quotes. Also you have mentioned in your subject `Google Sheets/Excel` but screeshot shows `Google Sheets` both applications are different use proper tags. anyone

Comment: Not true on the quotes part. I tried without quotes as well, it is always giving me #ERROR. I am using Google Sheets

Comment: `"20"` is not equivalent to `20`. Also why would you use `1` for the 3rd argument?

Comment: Guys, I've tried without quotes or with quotes, I tried even referencing another number in Cell ! Always #ERROR.
I just want to make it work otherwise after that I will adapt the VLOOKUP in another sheet, but I am aware of how to do this. It is about strange error that I cannot yet understand why it is happening.

Comment: @BigBen Sir, OP might have used `1` to return the same lookup value, thats fine but I think it may be float which is causing the error probably not sure

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya yeah agreed, I'd prefer `COUNTIFS` or `MATCH` then.

Comment: Yes, the data in A is this -> =Arrayformula(row(A2:A))
I'm using this for "AUTOINCREMENT" . @BigBen

Comment: @Svetoslav check for rounding errors. Can you increase the decimal places of the numbers in column A. Thanks

Comment: @Svetoslav I have tried using the same formula `=Arrayformula(row(A2:A))` and the using `VLOOKUP(20,A2:B33,1,FALSE)` works on my end

Comment: Yes, I think it is some kind of glitch or issue hard to solve. I read that if the table is sorted and has filters it is possible issue in such scenario ?

Comment: There you go. You can play with it. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/191FHeukOHpHUDMMqyaPGmObwV7U9ePZqP9RwkcjEmII/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: OP uses semicolon as a separator instead of comma.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I've never set it manually. It is probably because of my country where I live.. and no tutorial for many functions in the internet tell you to be aware for this. So glad that ztiaa knew even my default separator..

Comment: The `1` is returning the same value you’re looking up. You want to return the value in the column next to it `2` and the quotes will make a difference as one is a string and the other is a number.

Comment: @Svetoslav yes, that's why i commented because i was not aware of your settings and unfortunately it did not came into mind as well, unless i checked the sheet. thank you. I am not saying you have set it on your own, its by default. tks. Not necessarily everyone has to know everything, that is we learn from from here, when someone shares in `Answers`. `StackOverflow` great place to learn and enhance skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your spreadsheet is set to a locale (File > Settings > Locale) that uses commas as decimal separators, you have to separate the arguments with a semicolon, try:

```
=VLOOKUP(20; A2:B33; 2; FALSE)
```